# How can I remove spaces in between HTML tags using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup

I have the following problem:  when there is a space in between html tags, my code does not give me the text I want outputted.

Instead of outputting:

```
year|salary|bonus
2005|100,000|50,000
2006|120,000|80,000
```

I get this instead:

```
 |salary|bonus
2005|100,000|50,000
2006|120,000|80,000
```

the text "year" is not outputted.

Here's my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re


html = '<html><body><table><tr><td> <p>year</p></td><td><p>salary</p></td><td>bonus</td></tr><tr><td>2005</td><td>100,000</td><td>50,000</td></tr><tr><td>2006</td><td>120,000</td><td>80,000</td></tr></table></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.findAll('tr')

store=[]

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    row = []
    for td in cols:
        try:
            row.append(''.join(td.find(text=True)))
        except Exception:
            row.append('')
    store.append('|'.join(filter(None, row)))
print '\n'.join(store)
```

The problem comes from the space in:

```
"<td> <p>year</p></td>"
```

Is there a way to get rid of that space when I pull up some html from the web?

Comment: you should also use the ``csv`` module with a delimiter of '|' instead of just '|'.join()

Comment: What will that do for me?  Any guidance on how to do that?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: @Josh Lee: I see your recent batch of questions are all very incremental -- you're basically posting the 'answer' code from a previous answer and using it to ask your next question. You should be aware that, over time, this may lead your account to be placed in timed suspension; in fact, it's one of the main reasons listed at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/ .

Comment: @phooji: Thanks for the caution.  I'm new to Python and this Website.  I'll try to be more selective in my questions.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `row.append(''.join(td.find(text=True)))`, use :

```
row.append(''.join(td.text))
```

Output:

```
year|salary|bonus
2005|100,000|50,000
2006|120,000|80,000
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Herman suggested, you should use `Tag.text` to find the relevant text
for the tag you're currently parsing.

A bit more detail on why `Tag.find()` didn't do what you want: BeautifulSoup's
`Tag.find()` is very similar to to `Tag.findAll()`, in fact, its implementation
of `Tag.find()` just invokes `Tag.findAll()` with a keyword argument limit, set
to **1**. `Tag.findAll()` then recursively descends down the tag tree and returns
once it finds some text that satisfies the `text` argument. Since you set `text`
to `True`, the character "u' '" technically satisfies this condition and, thus,
is what is returned by `Tag.find()`.

In fact, you can see that year is returned if you print out `td.findAll(text=True, limit=2)`. You can also set `text` to a regular expression to ignore spaces, so you can then do `td.find(text=re.compile('[\S\w]'))`.

I also noticed that you're using `store.append('|'.join(filter(None, row)))`. I
think you should use the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), particularly the [csv.writer](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer). The CSV module handles all the problems that you might face if you have a pipe somewhere in your parsed html files, and, makes your code much cleaner.

Here's an example:

```
import csv
import re
from cStringIO import StringIO

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


html = ('<html><body><table><tr><td> <p>year</p></td><td><p>salary</p></td>'
        '<td>bonus</td></tr><tr><td>2005</td><td>100,000</td><td>50,000</td>'
        '</tr><tr><td>2006</td><td>120,000</td><td>80,000</td></tr></table>'
        '</html>')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.findAll('tr')

output = StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter='|')

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    row = []
    for td in cols:
        row.append(td.text)

    writer.writerow(filter(None, row))

print output.getvalue()
```

And the output is:

```
year|salary|bonus
2005|100,000|50,000
2006|120,000|80,000
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
html = re.sub(r'\s\s+', '', html)
```